# The ambiguity of complex conjugation $K$ for antilinear operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, schroedinger-equation, unitarity, time-reversal-symmetry

In Sakurai's book on Modern Quantum Mechanics 2nd Edition in p.288,

he mentioned the complex conjugation $K$ is required for antiunitary symmetry such as time reversal.

However, Sakurai also says that the $K$ only has to complex conjugate the coefficient such as $c$ below, but does not have to the complex conjugate the basis.

So
$$
K c |a> = c^* K |a>= c^*   |a>  \tag{1}
$$
and $K |a> =|a>$.
There is an ambiguity, if we change the basis to $|a> =\sum |a'><a'|a>$, then we have
$K|a'>=|a'> $ in the new basis $|a'>$, but then $K |a> = K (\sum |a'><a'|a>)=\sum |a'> <a'|a>^* \neq |a>.$

In summary,

1. we have in one case:
   $$
   K   |a> =|a>.
   $$
2. we have another case:
   $$
   K   |a'> =|a'>
   $$
   but
   $$K |a> = K (\sum |a'><a'|a>)=\sum |a'> <a'|a>^* \neq |a>.$$
   The two cases do not agree with each other, due to the way we define the complex conjugation respect to which basis.

### Question:

**Would the choice of this complex conjugation (respect to which bases) affect some subtle physics interpretations (or observables)? If yes, how? If not, how do we convince or avoid such ambiguity?**

It looks to relate to the math structure of how to complexify the algebra, $\otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C}$, any deeper comments are appreciated.

---

From Sakurai's book on Modern Quantum Mechanics 2nd Edition   p.288

[image]

Comment: If $\{|a>\}$ and $\{|a'>\}$ are two base kets for operator $K$, doesn't that imply $<a|a'>$ must be real entries?